# How do I use JavaScript regular expression to match the value of a string after an underscore?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use JavaScript regular expression to match the value of a string after an underscore, but ignoring an `s` at the end if there is one.

For example: `abcdefg_hijk` and `abcdefg_hijks` should both return `hijk`.

Comment: I've updated your question to reflect the "s" thing you mentioned in the comments on Matt Hulse's answer, and posted an answer showing you how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should give you what you're after:

```
var str = 'abcdefg_hijk';
var regex = /_(\w*)/;

str.match(regex)[1];  //returns hijk
```

Comment: One follow-up. How do I subtract the last letter IF it is 's'? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what your input is, but in this case: `var regex = /_(\w*)\w/;` will give you 'hij'.

Comment: I went back and edited it, but I meant to say if the last letter is 's'.

Comment: See @T.J.Crowder's answer for the regex excluding a final 's'.

Answer (score 4):

To do what you've described (including the "s" thing), the regular expression is `/_(.*?)s?$/`, example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ogunen)):

```
var regex = /_(.*?)s?$/;

display('abcdefg_hijk'.match(regex)[1]);    //returns hijk
display('abcdefg_hijks'.match(regex)[1]);   //returns hijk
display('abcdefg_hijkss'.match(regex)[1]);  //returns hijks
```

That regex says:

- `_` Look for an underscore
- `(.*?)` Match and capture a series of any characters following the underscore, non-greedy (that's what the `?` is).
- `s?` match an "s" following them if there is one, but don't capture it (here, `?` means "optional").
- `$` Marks the end of the string (important for the "s").

Recommend spending some time reading the [MDC page on `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), it's quite good.

Answer (score 2):

`var newString = 'abcdefg_hijk'.replace(/^[^_]*?_/, '');` to just scrub the front off and give you a new string with the remaining characters from the first underscore.

`var match = 'abcdefg_hijk'.match(/_(.*)$/);` to give you the match as in Munim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
var input = "abcdefg_hijk";
var regex = /.*_(.*)/i;
alert(input.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: The `i` flag does not make any difference here (`.` means any character already), and using `.*` without capturing can be eliminated as well (it matches anything, including nothing, anyway).